# Could someone explain to me what these Iterator, Yield monad types and functions mean like I am 5?

Tags: haskell

Below is the code. I understand applicative, functor, traversable and monad to a certain extent. The iterator and yield types, and yield functions are what I struggle understanding the most. For example, what are i o r in Iterator and i o r a in Yield? what does traverseY do exactly and what do the signatures mean? and How Monad Cont is applied here also confuses me a lot. Thank you for reading, any input would be appreciated.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.Random
import System.Random.Shuffle


data Iterator i o r =
    Result r
  | Susp o (i -> Iterator i o r)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
newtype Yield i o r a = Yield { unY :: Cont (Iterator i o r) a }

instance Functor (Yield i o r) where
  fmap f (Yield m) = Yield (fmap f m)

instance Applicative (Yield i o r) where
  pure a = Yield (pure a)
  (Yield mf) <*> (Yield ma) = Yield (mf <*> ma)

instance Monad (Yield i o r) where
  return a = Yield (return a)
  (Yield m) >>= k = Yield (m >>= \a -> unY (k a))

instance MonadCont (Yield i o r) where
  callCC c = Yield (callCC (\k -> unY (c (\a -> Yield (k a)))))

runYield :: Yield i o r r -> Iterator i o r
runYield (Yield m) = runCont m Result

yield :: o -> Yield i o r i
yield o = callCC (\k -> Yield (cont (\_ -> Susp o (\i -> runYield (k i)))))

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

traverseY :: Tree a -> Yield (Tree a) (a,Tree a,Tree a) r ()
traverseY Empty = return ()
traverseY (Node a t1 t2) = do t <- yield (a, t1, t2); traverseY t
```

Comment: I'm still absorbing this, but this is definitely not about execution time.

Comment: `Iterators` are just like Python generators. They alternate between waiting for inputs of type `i` and outputting outputs of type `o`, and at some point they will cease creating output and return a final value of type `r`. Compare `accum = go 0 where go n = if n >= 100 then Result n else Susp n (\i -> go $ n + i)` to Python `def accum(): { sum = 0; while sum < 100: { sum = sum + (yield sum); } return sum }` (replace braces with spaces ofc). No clue what `Yield` is useful for, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `Iterator i o r` represents a process that repeatedly takes a value of type `i` and outputs a value of type `o`, eventually breaking the iteration after one of the `i`s by returning a `r` instead. E.g.

```hs
accum :: Iterator Int Int Int
accum = go 0
  where go n | n >= 100 = Result n
             | otherwise = Susp n (\i -> go (n + i))
-- potential usage
main :: IO ()
main = go accum -- iterator returns modified copies instead of mutating, so prepare to replace the iterator through iteration/recursion
  where go (Result r) = putStrLn $ "Final total: " ++ show r -- check whether iterator has values/extract values by pattern matching; a finished iterator can return extra data of type r if it likes
        go (Susp o i) = do
          putStrLn $ "Running total: " ++ show o
          putStr $ "Add: "
          n <- readLn
          go (i n) -- bidirectional communication! get "incremented" iterator by feeding in an input value (you could write no-input iterators by setting i = ())
```

is an iterator that keeps track of some accumulator `n`. It adds each input to the accumulator and each time outputs the new accumulator. Once the accumulator reaches 100, it stops accepting input and returns the final value. Note that, since everything is immutable, in order to keep state, the `Iterator` has to *return a new version of itself* every time it changes state. Whoever is iterating "through" `accum` in turn has to use the returned `Iterator` instead of `accum` itself. In Python, you could write `accum` as:

```py
def accum(): # calling accum() instead creates a new object that mutates itself through iteration
  sum = 0
  while sum < 100: sum = sum + (yield sum)
  return sum

# same usage
def main():
  gen = accum()
  o = next(gen)
  try: # I was hoping the Python version would help understanding... but I think I overestimated how pythonic Python would be...
    while True:
      print(f"Running total: {o}")
      o = gen.send(int(input("Add: ")))
  except StopIteration as e:
    print(f"Final total: {e.value}")
```

`Yield i o r r` is being used as a "builder" for `Iterator i o r`. You can write an analogue of `Yield`'s interface for `Iterator` directly:

```
instance Functor (Iterator i o) where
  fmap f (Result x) = Result (f x)
  fmap f (Susp o i) = Susp o (fmap f . i)
instance Applicative (Iterator i o) where
  pure = Result
  liftA2 = liftM2
instance Monad (Iterator i o) where
  Result r >>= f = f r
  Susp o i >>= f = Susp o ((>>= f) . i)

-- yieldI x is the iterator that sends x to the caller and receives a value in return
-- in Python: def yieldI(x): return yield x
yieldI :: o -> Iterator i o i
yieldI x = Susp x Result
```

E.g. the generator in your DFS example is

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
dfsI :: Tree a -> Iterator b a (Tree b) -- yield elements of the tree (o = a) *and also* receive new elements to replace them (i = b), building a new tree (r = Tree b)
-- dfs = traverse yieldI
dfsI Empty = Result Empty
dfsI (Node l m r) = do
  l' <- yieldI l
  m' <- dfsI m
  r' <- dfsI r
  return (Node l' m' r')
```

The issue with using `Iterator i o r` directly here is that it is inefficient. (Remember that Haskell is lazily evaluated to understand the following.) If you "concatenate" many iterators, like `((x >>= f) >>= g) >>= h`, then you run into trouble when you try to evaluate it. Say `x` evaluates to `Susp o i`. Then evaluating the bigger expression first does three function calls, into the `>>=`s, evaluates `x` to `Susp o i`, then *creates new suspended function calls* to produce `Susp o (\a -> ((i a >>= f) >>= g) >>= h)`. When you iterate through this iterator (i.e. extract the lambda and call it with some argument), *each iteration* must walk through all the `>>=`s that are hanging on to the `Iterator`. Yikes. (Stated perhaps in more familiar terms, we've implemented iterator concatenation as a "wrapper" around another, which gets bad when you have wrappers on wrappers on wrappers...)

Using `Cont` is a "standard trick" for avoiding this. The idea is that, instead of handling an iterator `x` directly, we handle its bind function (wrapped in `Cont` and `Yield` newtypes) `x' = \f -> x >>= f`. Note that converting a monadic computation to its bind function is reversible, since `x' return = x >>= return = x`.

```
newtype Yield i o r a = Yield { unYield :: (a -> Iterator i o r) -> Iterator i o r }
instance Functor (Yield i o r) where
  fmap f (Yield r) = Yield (\k -> r $ k . f)
instance Applicative (Yield i o r) where
  pure x = Yield (\k -> k x)
  liftA2 = liftM2
instance Monad (Yield i o r) where
  Yield r >>= f = Yield (\k -> r $ \x -> unYield (f x) k)
-- newtype Yield i o r a = Yield { unYield :: (a -> Iterator i o r) -> Iterator i o r }
-- compare         (>>=) :: Iterator i o a -> (a -> Iterator i o r) -> Iterator i o r
-- giving
liftIY :: Iterator i o a -> Yield i o r a
liftIY x = Yield (x >>=)
-- and the law x >>= return = x inspires
runYield :: Yield i o r r -> Iterator i o r
runYield (Yield r) = r return
-- e.g.
yield :: o -> Yield i o r i
-- yield = liftIY . yieldI
yield x = Yield (\k -> Susp x (\i -> k i)) -- note this is the same as yours after you drill through newtype baggage
```

Instead of having `((x >>= f) >>= g) >>= h`, using `Yield` will make terms like `(((x' >>= liftIY . f) >>= liftIY . g) >>= liftIY . h) return` appear at runtime. This evaluates to just `x' >>= _someFunction`, so all the wrappers from before have collapsed into just one, hopefully leading to efficiency. (This collapsed wrapper will "replace itself" as you iterate through, going through the behaviors specified by `f`, `g`, and `h` in turn. This is encoded in `Yield`'s `>>=`.)

```
-- magical free efficiency by replacing Iterator -> Yield, yieldI -> yield
dfs :: Tree a -> Yield b a r (Tree b)
dfs = traverse yield
-- when using Yields as builders, you will treat Yield i o _ r like Iterator i o r
-- the middle parameter should be polymorphic for builders like dfs
-- while the final consumer (particularly the "standard consumer" runYield) fixes it to something (runYield sets it to the final return type)
-- (this behavior is a loosely typed reflection of the Codensity monad)
```

At the final use site, `Yield`s have to be made into `Iterator`s before they can be iterated. Your `dfsDirect`:

1. Uses `dfs = traverse yieldI` to build a `Yield` without incurring the wrath of "accidentally quadratic left associativity" (technical term :))
2. Builds an `Iterator` out of that `Yield` using `runYield`. This iterator goes through `tr` and yields/replaces its elements.
3. Iterates that iterator via `loop`, which...
4. "Converses" with `dfs` via the line `loop (Susp o i) = loop (i [o])`: when it receives `o` it sends `[o]` back into the iterator, which puts it in the `Tree` it's building.
5. Upon exhausting the iterator, receives a new `Tree` where every element is replaced with a singleton list (`loop (Result r) = _`).
6. Concatenates all the lists together via the `Foldable Tree` instance.

This is a pretty dumb way to do things, since the order doesn't come from `dfs` but from the `Foldable Tree` instance used in the last step. The `Iterator` is just used as a glorified `fmap` function. If the `Foldable` instance were different (e.g. BFS, or even just inorder vs preorder), but you kept `dfs` as a preorder DFS (so it would no longer be written `traverse yield`), `dfsDirect` would not output in the actual order defined by `dfs`! You could write a function that *properly* turns an `Iterator` into a list.

```
-- note the usage of () as an input type for "plain" iterators
-- since we cannot know what to pass in otherwise 
iToList :: Iterator () o r -> ([o], r)
iToList (Result r) = ([], r)
iToList (Susp o i) = (o : os, r)
  where ~(os, r) = iToList (i ())
```

`traverseY` is also a bit strange. If it receives a `Node` (either as initial value or as an iterator input), it yields back the fields of the `Node`, and on `Empty` else it returns. It doesn't actually "traverse" its input; you can send it off into a completely new tree just by sending that tree as input. I assume the idea is that when you iterate over it, you send back one of the `Tree`s it previously returned, so it iterates over a *path* to a leaf. IMO it would be nicer to write

```
data Direction = L | R
path :: Tree a -> Yield Direction a r () -- outputs root and goes in direction as told until it runs out of tree
path Empty = pure ()
path (Node x l r) = do
  d <- yield x
  case d of
    L -> path l
    R -> path r
-- potential use
elemBST :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
elemBST x xs = go (runYield $ path xs)
  where go (Result ()) = False -- iteration ended without success
        go (Susp y i) = case compare x y of
          LT -> go (i L) -- go left
          EQ -> True     -- end
          GT -> go (i R) -- go right
```